# How to create a Vaadin form for a domain class that has aggregations (without JPA Container)?

Tags: java, grails, persistence, grails-orm, vaadin

I have a application using Vaadin version 6.8.0 (via the Grails Vaadin plugin version 1.5.4).

If I have a Java domain class *Issue* that has a 1:1 relationship to another class *File*, what is the best way to write an *IssueForm* to create new Issues and edit existing ones, without the (premium) Vaadin JPA Container?

In the form, I want to display a ComboBox to chose one *File* of all the available Files. 
I already know I can do something like this in the *IssueForm* constructor:

```
  setFormFieldFactory(new DefaultFieldFactory() {
        @Override
        public Field createField(Item item, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
            if (propertyId.equals("cover")) {
                ComboBox cb = new ComboBox("Cover")
                for (FileListItem fileListItem : fileService.getAllFilesForCategory()) {
                    cb.addItem(fileListItem);
                }

                return cb;
            } else {
                Field field = super.createField(item, propertyId, uiContext);
                return field;
            }
        }
    });
```

- If I use DTOs to connect the Vaadin beans to my Java domain classes, would IssueListItem need to reference FileListItem? Or File directly?
- Can I automagically populate the selected File (or FileListItem?) in the new/edited Issue? How? If not, how to approach this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "automagically populate the selected File"? What exactly should happen with the combobox or with domain classes...?

Answer (score 0):

If you use DTOs, then yes: IssueListItem needs to reference FileListItem and then on the other place you transform IssueListItem and FileListItem to domain persistent classes Issue and File.